# special column convert to json

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have created the class as below :

```
public class StudentRecord
{
    [Key]
    public Int ID { get; set; }
    public String StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason, I need to do

```
 list<StudentRecord> getStudentData = fnGetData(); // Get all data from SQL
 string jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getStudentData);
```

But I just want `jsondata` only get column `StudentName` only.
That mean example of data is

```
[ "Peter", "Mary", "Sam", "Kim", "Hey" ]
```

Can I know how to do this ?

Thank you

Comment: It seems to me that you would do better to project the student objects to strings (perhaps using LINQ's `.Select` method), and then serialize that.

Comment: Json is just a serialisation of something. If that something is a list of student, you get a json with the a list of student. With everything that define a student. If you want a list of names. You should pass a list of name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select `StudentName` into `List` then  `SerializeObject` as you wish.

```
list<StudentRecord> getStudentData = fnGetData(); // Get all data from SQL
var studentNameList = getStudentData.Select(p => p.StudentName).ToList(); 
string jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(studentNameList);
```

**Updated**

If you want to get one more columns, you can do it by return list of [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) like this

```
var studentNameList = getStudentData.Select(p => new { p.StudentName, p.ID }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. if I want to get one more column, e.g. the class have 3 columns, I need to take 2 columns, can you advise ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore the column, you can add the annotation `[JsonIgnore]`:

```
public class StudentRecord
{
    [Key]
    public Int ID { get; set; }

    public String StudentName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public String PropertyToIgnore{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Linq queries to select the required attribute from a collection of objects

```
  string jsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getStudentData.Select(s=>s.StudentName).ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks. if I want to get one more column, e.g. the class have 3 columns, I need to take 2 columns, can you advise ?